# Migration to AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, cloud

I have one DC server on premise. In this server I have Microsoft AD configured, DNS and a shared drive to a NAS Device. I want to take this entire infra to AWS Cloud.

What all services will I use and what will be my estimate?

Comment: With a bit of focusing, this question might be more suited to https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

From my experience from helping enterprise customers, you should be migrating your present AD to AWS Managed Microsoft AD.

Documentation on AWS MS AD (managed service) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_microsoft_ad.html.

Migration documentation - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-migrate-your-on-premises-domain-to-aws-managed-microsoft-ad-using-admt/

Answer (score 0):

Go with the AWS Managed AD service as Robin points out. This also includes a DNS service and the offering is designed for high availability.

For the File Share, go for Amazon FSx. It supports both Cloud and On-Prem clients as long as there's VPN/Direct Connect line between your on-prem network and the AWS cloud/VPC. Here's more: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server-now-supports-on-premises-access/

Answer (score 0):

1. After you create your access in AWS, you can ask for aws suport to earn USD 300 in credits that you can use for your labs. So, you could try by yourself the entire environment.
2. Windows Server EC2 Instance is the server you can use (the price depends on the type of instance. vCPU, memmory and storage of it). AWS also offers a DC serverless.
3. How to know the right type of the instance in terms of hardware?
   R: you can use AWS Migration Hub service (create server, application) and install the "AWS Discovery Agent" in your on-premises server. After some hours or days, the installed agent will fill the "AWS Migration Hub" created application with rich informations about network, cpu, memmory and will suggest the type of instance, example: m4.xlarge.
4. You can use your windows server licence there.
5. FSX is a way to share files between servers in the cloud and to on-premises computers. If you want to share files only in the cloud environment, you can share by using an EBS volume attached directly - as a disk - to the server.